# Qt Overlay over GStreamer

Tags: qt, gstreamer, yocto, imx6, eglfs

**I've a question considering the current setup:**

- Yocto Linux on `iMX6`
- Neither a window-, nor a display-manager
- A fully functional Qt Application, tested on Debian 9

**The application consists of 2 main elements:**

- A `GStreamer` part, with a imxg2dvideosink
- A semi-transparent Qt Overlay, which should be displayed over the stream

**The question:**

How can I accomplish to display the overlay over the stream, while having both parts on fullscreen (filling the whole screen)? *Possible solutions:*

- `/dev/fb1` as an overlay to `/dev/fb0` (How to split a single application to two `fb`'s ?)
- Use a display-manager ?
- Use a window-manager ?
- `linuxfb` instead of `eglfs` ?

**My current (not working) solution:**

- Using `-platform eglfs`
- The application will first start `GStreamer`, and afterwards show the overlay

Comment: You need to write own GStreamer sink unless you know how to make imxg2dvideosink to render where you want it to render.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the solution myself. Shared below:

**1) Run Qt Application on `/dev/fb1`:**

- `export QT_QPA_EGLFS_FB=/dev/fb1` (Specify `/dev/fb1` as `eglfs` framebuffer)
- `echo 0 > /sys/class/graphics/fb1/blank` (Unblank framebuffer)
- `fbset -fb /dev/fb1 --geometry <your geometry here>` (Set framebuffer geometry)
- `./YourApplication -platform eglfs` (Run application)

Use a Color Key if you want full opacity while having fully transparent parts of your overlay.

**2) Run GStreamer on `/dev/fb0`:**

- `gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! imxg2dvideosink framebuffer=/dev/fb0`

This is the solution for `eglfs`. Other possibilities are `linuxfb`.